# Issue when importing an Adobe Fuse model

Tags: modeling, import, obj

I'm trying to import a model that I made with Fuse. But everytime I try to import my .obj model I have this message.

[image]
If you have any solution I would really apperciate ;)

Comment: Perhaps you've changed the default colormanagement folder that ships with Blender? Maybe to [this](https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender)?

Comment: Yes I have filmic blender but even with the sRGB profile it doesn't import :/

Comment: Seems the importer won't work with Filmic Blender.